# CLI How to continuously check for change

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, command-line-interface

Im trying to check for input continuously from the cli. But for some reason when I enter say "r" into the cli ill have to do it a few times before it actually goes into the if statement. Im not sure why it has to do this. Then when it does and I enter say "s" it might never read it.

Does anyone know why this is or a better way to continuously check for user input and be able to act on it

Thanks

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
              if (sc.next().equals("r")) {
                thread1.start();
                System.out.println("r");
             }
            if (sc.next().equals("s")) {
                thread1.interrupt;
                System.out.println("s");
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to save sc.next() in a local variable before testing.